# How to redirect errors to a variable

Tags: powershell, redirect

I have a script that pass over files and I want to redirect any errors to a variable and print them in the end of the script.
Here is example for a problem I am getting:

```
 Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\appcompat -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
            # do stuff ...
        }
```

Sometimes there are folders that I don't have access to them and it throws exception:
[image]
I know how to ignore these errors and continue using the switch `-ErrorAction`, but I wanted to collects all the folders that I don't have access and print them in the end of the script.

With [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-6) it is possible to use `2>` which will redirect the errors to a file:

```
 Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\appcompat -Recurse 2> errors.txt | ForEach-Object {
    # do stuff ...
}
```

Is it possible to redirect, only the errors, to a variable and then I will print them in the end of the script ?

Comment: There's the `$Error` variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can **use the [common `-ErrorVariable` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters) to collect a cmdlet's errors in a *variable***.

Since this collecting happens *in addition* to errors getting sent to the error stream, as usual, you must **explicitly silence the error-stream output with `2>$null` if you want the collecting to be *silent***.

Therefore, in order to silently collect errors in, say, variable `$errs`, use the following:

```
# Shorter equivalent of `-ErrorVariable errs`: `-ev errs`
Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\appcompat -Recurse -ErrorVariable errs 2>$null | ForEach-Object {
            # do stuff ...
}
```

Note:

- The short alias name for `-ErrorVariable` is `-ev`
- Be sure *not* to prefix the target variable name with `$` - you're passing its *name*, not its value.
- Do not use the name `Errors`, because `$Errors` is the automatic (built-in) variable in which all errors that have occurred in the session are being collected.
- The target variable receives a collection of type `[System.Collections.ArrayList]` containing `[System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]` instances.

  - Note you get a collection even in the case of only a *single* error having occurred, which may be surprising, given that PowerShell usually *unwraps* single-element collections; this surprising behavior is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3773).

Unfortunately, **this convenient error-collecting mechanism is *not* available when calling *external programs*** (e.g., when you call `git`), because such calls do not support common parameters; however, there is a [suggestion on GitHub to introduce an alternative syntax](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4332).